# Displaying csv data in the browser with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running into issues scraping pages which download `text/csv` data with Selenium.

So far, if I need to scrape a csv file which I have a URL for, I can use the Firefox driver and prepend the URL with `view-source:` to make it display the contents of the file in the browser which allows it to be scraped, e.g. `view-source:https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/E0.csv`.

But if this csv data is being served up dynamically, behind a button click for example then I don't have a URL to prepend and the Firefox node attempts to download the file instead of displaying it.

I have tried setting `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile` to `text/csv` in `about:config` in a Firefox browser on my desktop but the file still downloads.

I am using `selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59` and `selenium/hub:3.141.59` docker images in my service, so downloading files to a location would be fiddly to manage.

Is there another browser property or approach I can use to ensure that any csv data download appears in the browser rather than gets written to file?

Rich

Comment: I don't know, but if the csv is displayed as a table then you can create a pandas dataframe